# Как работают регулярные выражения в js?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка `'IM'">Сегодня 12:36</span>`
Хочу получить из него дату

Пробуют таким образом

```
var regex = '/(?<=IM>).+?(?=<)/';
var text = ''IM'">Сегодня 12:36</span>';
var result = text.match(regex);
console.log(result);
```

Почему то не работает такая регулярка. Что не так? В онлайн сервисах регулярка отрабатывает корректно

Answer (score 3):

В этом регулярном выражении использовано [lookbehind assertion](http://exploringjs.com/es2018-es2019/ch_regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html). Это относительно новое свойство языка и оно ещё не везде поддерживается, [зависит от типа и версии браузера или Node.js](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Lookbehind_Assertions).

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать получить дату с помощь групп. Примерно так:

```js
var text = `'IM'">Сегодня 12:36</span>`;
var pattern = new RegExp('IM\'">(.+?)<\/');

console.log(text.match(pattern)[1]);
```